# default values for IP_MULTICAST_IF

Tags: c, udp, multicast

I am trying to figure out, what default values are used for the IP_MULTICAST_IF option after setting up a new socket. Unfortunately my code segfaults and I actually don't know why?! Am I doing something wrong, or how to I get the default values for the IP_MULTICAST_IF option?

```
  int sock;
  struct in_addr interface_addr;
  int addr_size;

  if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {
    perror("socket() failed");
  }

  addr_size = sizeof(interface_addr);

  if ((getsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, &interface_addr, &addr_size)) <  0) {
    perror("getsockopt() failed");
  }

  printf("The default interface is %s\n", inet_ntoa(interface_addr));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, my code was missing  an include. With

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Read the `ip(7)` man page for your platform. `IP_MULTICAST_IF` doesn't take give an `struct in_addr`.

On Linux:

> ```
> IP_MULTICAST_IF (since Linux 1.2)
>         Set the local device for a multicast socket.  Argument is an  ip_mreqn  or
>         ip_mreq  structure similar to IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP.
>         When an invalid socket option is passed, ENOPROTOOPT is returned.
>
> IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP (since Linux 1.2)
>           Join a multicast group.  Argument is an ip_mreqn structure.
>
>              struct ip_mreqn {
>                   struct in_addr imr_multiaddr; /* IP multicast group
>                                                    address */
>                   struct in_addr imr_address;   /* IP address of local
>                                                    interface */
>                   int            imr_ifindex;   /* interface index */
>               };
>           imr_multiaddr  contains  the  address  of the multicast group the application wants to join or
>           leave.  It must be a valid multicast address (or setsockopt(2) fails with the  error  EINVAL).
>           imr_address is the address of the local interface with which the system should join the multi‐
>           cast group; if it is equal to INADDR_ANY an appropriate interface is  chosen  by  the  system.
>           imr_ifindex  is  the interface index of the interface that should join/leave the imr_multiaddr
>           group, or 0 to indicate any interface.
>           The ip_mreqn structure is available only since Linux 2.2.  For compatibility, the old  ip_mreq
>           structure  (present  since Linux 1.2) is still supported; it differs from ip_mreqn only by not
>           including the imr_ifindex field.  Only valid as a setsockopt(2).
> ```

Comment: For some reason, it seems that the Segmentation Fault comes from the inet_ntoa(..). Even when I correct the struct to an ip_mreq struct - I still get the same Segmentation Fault.

Comment: `       IP_MULTICAST_IF (since Linux 1.2)
              Set the local device for a multicast socket.  The argument for setsockopt(2) is an ip_mreqn or (since Linux 3.5)  ip_mreq  structure  similar  to
              IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,  or  an  in_addr  structure.  (The kernel determines which structure is being passed based on the size passed in optlen.)  For
              getsockopt(2), the argument is an in_addr structure.`